# Weird behaviour while reading table in R from text file

Tags: r, read.table

This question may be trivial but can anyone answer why it is happening:

So while trying to read table we give correct path. But after pressing enter key the R throws up error saying invalid path because it adds * automatically in front of the path.

Before pressing Enter:

```
 read.table("C:\\Users\\prudh\\Downloads\\SENIC.txt")
```

After pressing Enter

```
read.table("*C:\\Users\\prudh\\Downloads\\SENIC.txt")  # * Added by R
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
cannot open file '*C:\Users\prudh\Downloads\SENIC.txt': Invalid argument
```

Comment: Remove the asterisk?

Comment: The R adds star automatically

Comment: What is shown by `list.files("C:\\Users\\prudh\\Downloads")`

Comment: It shows 0 but the files are there for sure.

Comment: R did not add that `*`, because it processes commands, it doesn't normally echo them.  It must have been added by your front-end (RStudio?  Rgui? ESS?) or some other software on your system.  The warning message is strange too:  normally `read.table` would warn `No such file or directory`, not `Invalid argument`.